# How to instantiate classes in one class and use it as adapter

Tags: python

What is a more effective way to instantiate all classes in one class and use it as interface that will activate methods of these instances ?
In reality, every class will contain multiple methods and data variables, and I do not want to create one huge class with many methods.
Please, share you code.

For example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.match = "number"
        self.num = 10

    def shoot(self):
        return self.num

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.match = "number"
        self.num = 20

    def shoot(self):
        return self.num

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.match = "word"
        self.word = "Some beautiful word"

    def shoot(self):
        return self.word


class AllClasses:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()
        self.c = C()
        self.all_instances = [
            instance
            for name, instance in vars(self).items()
        ]

    def shoot_numbers(self):
        for instance in self.all_instances:
            if hasattr(instance, "match") and instance.match == "number":
                print(instance.shoot())

    def shoot_words(self):
        for instance in self.all_instances:
            if hasattr(instance, "match") and instance.match == "word":
                print(instance.shoot())


inst = AllClasses()
inst.shoot_numbers()
inst.shoot_words()
```

Another example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.match = "task 1"
        self.task = "Go"

    def do(self):
        return self.task

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.match = "task 2"
        self.task = "Sit"

    def do(self):
        return self.task

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.match = "task 3"
        self.task = "Stay"

    def do(self):
        return self.task

class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task = "Leave"

    def do(self):
        return self.task

class AllClasses:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()
        self.c = C()
        self.d = D()
        self.all_instances = [
            instance
            for name, instance in vars(self).items()
        ]
        
    def do_task(self, task: str):
        matched = False
        for instance in self.all_instances:
            if hasattr(instance, "match") and instance.match == task:
                matched = True
                print(instance.do())
        if not matched:
            print(self.d.do())


tasks = [
    "task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4", "task 5"
]

inst = AllClasses()
for task in tasks:
    inst.do_task(task)
```

In real example, I am trying to create something like Adapter Design Pattern for data manipulation. I will try to explain it below:

Lets assume I have a data structure as Tuples that comes from data source connection as generator as 1 million tuples (rows).

There will be several classes, and each class will look for his data by values in tuple.
When class will find his matched value and it will change other value in the tuple.
When class will not find such a value it will pass.
The main class will be the "adapter" that will look for matching values in tuple for specific class and activate methods of this class, as result it will return values as new changed tuple that has been created in specific class.

Thank you for your time and support,

Comment: why not inherit the classes into `AllClasses`?

Comment: `A`,  `B` and `C` are effectively identical, and could be instances of the same class. Can yuo explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? This looks like it could be an X/Y problem...

Comment: What do you think is the difference between an abstraction or an 'abc' package?

Comment: I don't think your second example really helps.  As @match says, this looks like an X/Y problem, can you be more explicit on what you're trying to **achieve** with these examples you've shown?  It is quite likely there's a more suitable way of doing it.

Comment: @defladamouse , Thank you for your time and support. In order to avoid X/Y problem I have changed the question and added sort explanation of what I want to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @match mentioned in a comment, `A`, `B`, and `C` are almost identical and could be instance of the same class.

There are lots of ways to do this, but here is one example of such a class:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class myClass:
    num : int = None
    word : str = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        
        # Determine `match` based on whether a number or word was passed
        self.match = "number" if self.num is not None else "word"        
    
    def shoot(self):

        if self.match=="number":
            return self._shoot_number()
        elif self.match=="word":
            return self._shoot_word()
        
    def _shoot_number(self):
        return self.num
    
    def _shoot_word(self):
        return self.word
```

You can then create a list of instances of your class, rather than creating `AllClasses`:

```
my_classes = [
    myClass(num=10),
    myClass(num=20),
    myClass(word="Some beautiful word"),
]
```

And then print the numbers or words:

```
for my_class in my_classes:
    print(my_class.shoot())
```

However, if this does not fit with what you're trying to achieve, please edit your question to give a more detailed description.